# Duplicate or Exact Duplicate

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, close-reasons

I suppose I should know this but just noticed [in the 10K tools](https://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=close) on the Close tab, that if you sort the Reopen queue by hitting the 'sort by close reason' option, that it has the reason **duplicate** and **exact duplicate**.

What is the logic for the questions being in one category or the other?

Edit: Here's a current example that doesn't meet the explanation in BradleyDotNET's answer:

[image]

and the link for it: [Why are ToLookup and GroupBy different?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10215428/why-are-tolookup-and-groupby-different)

Comment: Time of closing?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
select * from CloseReasonTypes
```

```
Id  Name                       Description                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
--- -------------------------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
1   exact duplicate            This question covers exactly the same content as earlier questions on this topic; its answers may be merged with another identical question.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
2   off topic                  Questions on Stack Overflow are expected to relate to programming or software development within the scope defined in the FAQ. Consider editing the question or leaving comments for improvement if you believe the question can be reworded to fit within the scope. Read more about closed questions here.                      
3   not constructive           As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A format. We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion. If you feel that this question can be improved and possibly reopened, see the FAQ for guidance. 
4   not a real question        It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form. For help clarifying this question so that it can be reopened, see the FAQ.                                                                                        
7   too localized              This question is unlikely to help any future visitors; it is only relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet. For help making this question more broadly applicable, see the FAQ.                             
10  general reference          null                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
20  noise of pointless         null                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
101 duplicate                  null                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
102 off-topic                  null                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
103 unclear what you're asking null                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
104 too broad                  null                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
105 primarily opinion-based    null                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          

(12 row(s) affected)
```

We changed the close reasons a while back. All of them. Even the ones that were pretty similar to what already existed; it was just simpler that way.

This means there are a handful of votes still floating around that use the old reasons. Hint: the old ones are the ones with Ids less than 100.

Comment: Can we have "noise of pointless" back? I haven't seen that one yet... ;)

Comment: What does it mean that the new ones don't have a description?

Comment: It means we've moved them into specially-structured code, @Bergi, so that our translation system can easily extract and replace them as-needed. This technique is now pervasive in our user interface, allowing us to ship over most of the strings you see to be translated en masse, thus saving folks like my co-worker jmac *hundreds of hours* that they might otherwise have to spend translating them piecemeal.

Answer (score 5):

"Exact Duplicate" questions are those whose targets have no answers.

"Duplicate" questions are all other duplicates.

On Stack Overflow you'll only see "Exact Duplicate" in the close review queue if the target post *has the same author*, since regular users can't VTC as a duplicate of any other question with no answers.

Thanks to @animuson for clearing my understanding of this feature up.

Comment: Exact duplicate is actually used when the other question has no answers. It's just that on Stack Overflow, regular users can only vote to close in that scenario when the authors are the same. See [What decides what to prepend the duplicate question list with on a duplicate question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197452/what-decides-what-to-prepend-the-duplicate-question-list-with-on-a-duplicate-que/197454#197454)

Comment: @animuson Ah, I didn't realize that restriction was special that way. Thanks for the info! Edited to fix

Comment: Any ideas then why this one is marked as an exact duplicate, since neither condition applies, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10215428/why-are-tolookup-and-groupby-different.

Comment: @LanceRoberts That doesn't render as an exact duplicate to me. Just the standard duplicate text.

Comment: Just posted pic into question.

Comment: This is probably a distinction somewhere, but it's completely irrelevant to what Lance is observing.

Comment: @Shog9 Yeah, now that the picture is posted it seems odd that he sees that. Going to the question itself yields the expected result.

Comment: I just ran into a situation where it was two very-low-rep accounts, but the **exact** same question. Clearly someone registered a new account in order to post the 2nd question. But I can't vote to close as duplicate, but neither question has any answers. Was forced to use a moderator flag.